# Unable to use multiple images in a single node to create a a slideshow in Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

First take a look at my node setup here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/irhpy.jpg

The first image is my Subpage slider content type which accepts multiple images and will essentially be my slideshow.

Second image is the default page, but I added a node reference to the Subpage slider node. It allows you to associate a particular slideshow to a page.

The last image I was messing around with Views and Views Slideshow, but I don't know what I'm doing. I managed to get images displayed, but as you can see it displays the images of a long vertically. I set the Views slideshow and it creates a slide between multiple nodes and not the multiple images in ONE node.

Where do I go from here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To display a block with a slideshow of images (from a referenced node) when viewing a page**

I have come up with a much easier ("duh" moment) way of doing this. I created the functionality on a fresh Drupal install. Assuming you have the following modules: [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) (w/ Node Reference enabled), [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow), [FileField](http://drupal.org/project/filefield), [ImageField](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield).

1. Create your content types (in this case: *slider* and using the core *page* type)
2. Add an imagefield to the *slider* content type (field should be named `field_images`)
3. Add a node reference field to the core *page* content type (field should be named `field_slide_ref`)
4. Edit the node reference field settings (can remove "Required" if you like)
   [image: Node reference settings]
5. Create a new view called *slideshow*
6. In the *slideshow* view:

   - Change `Basic Settings->Style` to "Slideshow"
   - Add the field "Content: images" (choose `Format: Image` at bottom, unless using [ImageCache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache))
   - Add an argument of "Node: Nid" with the settings:
     [image: Argument Settings]
   - Add a "block" display
7. Enable your new block labeled "slideshow: Block" at `example.com/admin/build/block`

If configured correctly, when viewing a *page* with the _slide_ref_ field referencing a *slider* node, you should see the slideshow displayed in the block.

---

**Old Solution...**

To display a referenced slideshow **inside** the page node being viewed:

1. Download, install and enable the [View Reference module](http://drupal.org/project/viewreference)
2. Create your content type with multiple images (Subpage slider) **[Done]**
3. Create a new "page" view in Views UI. Add the field `Content: YOUR_IMAGEFIELD` (from Subpage slider) **important:** don't group the images, under `Basic Settings->Style` choose "Slideshow" and add an Argument of `Node: nid` choosing `Provide default argument->Node ID from URL` as argument settings
4. Create a view reference field on your *page* content type where you want to see the slideshow and select the view(s) that can be referenced and in the "Arguments" fieldset check: `Allow delimiter seperated values` and click "Save field settings"

Now when you create a *default page* there will be a view reference field to select the view you want to use and an argument field where you can input the node id of the node with your images you want to show as a slideshow in your page.

Comment: thanks. Here are some problems I've run into following your instructions: Creating a Page View it asks me for a "Path" which I enter "about" because that is where I want my slider to be. I don't know what this does. Next, there is no preview and no queries are run. Is this supposed to happen? I add the View Reference to my Page content type and I add my slider View and the node of 106 as the argument which is my node ID, but I get nothing. How does the "page view" display? Within the <?php print $content ?> along with my existing page node body content? Thanks.

Comment: ah! ok i typed 106 in the preview argument field and I got it! However, it still doesnt show up on my actual page

Comment: ok so I added a path in the Page View and called it /boo/% and that shows my page. I guess what Im looking for is a block to place it on my existing pages. My next issue is that the View Slideshow is not working even though when I firebug I see all my images in the structure.

Comment: @Adam Do you want the same block for all pages, or for the slideshow to change depending on which node is shown?

Comment: well yes the same block but different slideshow node depending on the page node. So "about us" and "contact" will get get slideshow1 and "reservations" slideshow2

Comment: I think i have everything working now except for the View Reference field. I create a block and placed it in my "content" region just to test. Nothing is showing up other than my page's body content

Comment: Obviously my argument isnt getting passed. I'm just typing 106 in the textfield, but i have feeling there's more to that to pass to a block view

Comment: @Adam no I don't believe it is. I was under the impression you wanted the slideshow **in** the page content, which is how I had it working with these instructions.  Getting the slideshow in a block has proved problematic.

Comment: @Adam See the new solution at the top of my answer to display slideshow in a block. It is much simpler and IMO better.

Comment: amazing. Works the way I wanted it to. Thanks!

Comment: Any ideas why it only shows when im logged in into the admin area?

Comment: Not really, may want to check the block settings for _display on this page_ etc. Also make sure the correct permissions are set for the imagefield, view, etc

Answer (score 1):

THE QUICK SOLUTION: a really simple tweak which the Views Slideshow docs should put in lurid bold gothic writing:

If you want to slideshow multiple images from an image field of one node **** don't forget to untick the "Group multiple values" checkbox in the settings for your-view>Fields>your-image-field ****

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add as argument not the 'node id' but the 'slideref field' and provide default argument 'nid by url' and the slideshow by node will work.

You can use the Views Nivo Slider as well.

Answer (score 0):

This outlines how to make a slideshow of images that are taken from one node. The main point here is that you have to make a block that has an argument of node id taken from the url. I used this to make a slideshow showing as a block in the main content area, but you can of course put the block anywhere.

Modules:

CCK
imagefield
views
views_slideshow OR jCarosel

1. Create your Content Type with an image field, allowing multiple values.

   1. Create content with multiple images, distinct enough so that you can tell if the images are from one particular node or another node
2. Create a new view as a node.

   1. Create a Block display
   2. Give your block a name (under Block Settings, left column)
   3. Filter as: published, as your Content Type and with the image field (important - see last step why).
   4. Field: your image field.

      1. Make sure to uncheck the 'Group multiple values' checkbox
      2. Display as an image, or an imagecache preset. Whatever you like
   5. Add an argument:

      1. Node: NID
      2. For 'Action to take if argument is not present', select 'Provide Default Argument'
      3. Node ID from URL
   6. Under 'Basic Settings' select

      1. If using views_slideshow, select the Style to be: Slideshow (Single-frame).
      2. Items to display: unlimited
   7. Save your View
3. Go to your Blocks page (/admin/build/block) and place your newly created block into the main content area (or wherever you want it to be). If you need to set the visibility on the actual block itself (/admin/build/block) then go ahead but otherwise only nodes of the content type that has multiple images will show the slideshow of images, while other pages on your site will not. This is why it is important to set a specific filter and to use the argument.
   Done!

Essentially, this does not work as a page but has to be a block. The slideshow will use the NID to see what images are in that node and create a slideshow of those only.

Should work the same in Drupal 7 but have not tested this.